# Why does execv exit a function?

Tags: c, exec

Here is the unix v6 code: http://v6shell.org/history/if.c

```
doex(earg) {
...
execv(ncom, nargv, np);
return(1);
}
```

So if execv is successfully executed, we will not reach the next line and return 1. Instead execv will return something (0?) and exit the function doex.
**But why?**

I would except you would have to write this:

```
if ( execv(ncom, nargv, np) ) return (0);
return (1);
```

unix v6 exec - man page: http://man.cat-v.org/unix-6th/2/exec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the start of the `exec` man page you linked:

> Exec overlays the calling process with the named file, then
>   transfers to the beginning of the core image of the file.
>   **There can be no return from the file**; the calling core image
>   is lost.

Just like in [today's `exec` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), the `execv` call fully replaces the calling process with a new one. If `execv` failed for some reason, control will pass to the next line and the function will `return 1`. Otherwise, the exit code of the subprocess will be used as the exit code of this process, and no further code from this process will execute.